# How to shorten list by grouping values that appear multiple times in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list that's something like this:

```
foo = ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo','bar']
```

and I want it to be converted to something like this:

```
'1-3 = bar'
'4-5 = foo'
'6 = bar'
```

The conversion needs to be done automatically, to accommodate list changes. How would I go about automating this?

Comment: Do you also want a way to convert your condensed version back to a normal list?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus No, it's not sorted. And "alrd" isn't a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution (without `groupby` from `itertools`):

```
foo = ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo','bar']

def my_groupby(l):
    first, last, current_value = 0, 0, l[0]
    for i, value in enumerate(l):
        if value != current_value:
            yield first + 1, last + 1, current_value
            current_value, first, last = value, i, i
        else:
            last = i
    yield first + 1, last + 1, current_value

for first, last, value in my_groupby(foo):
    if first != last:
        print(f'{first}-{last} = {value}')
    else:
        print(f'{first} = {value}')
```

Prints:

```
1-3 = bar
4-5 = foo
6 = bar
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby
foo = ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo','bar']
pos = 1
for k, g in groupby(foo):
    count = sum(1 for _ in g)
    if count == 1:
        print('%d = %s' % (pos, k))
    else:
        print('%d - %d = %s' % (pos, pos + count - 1, k))
    pos += count
```

This outputs:

```
1 - 3 = bar
4 - 5 = foo
6 = bar
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you really want,but you can count elements

```
>>> foo = ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo','bar']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(foo)
Counter({'bar': 4, 'foo': 2})
```

Or

```
>>> ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo','bar'].count('bar')
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start_value = foo[0]
start_position = 0
for entry in range(1, len(foo)):
    if start_value == foo[entry]:
        pass
    else:
        print(str(start_position+1) + " - " + str(entry) + " = " + start_value)
        start_value = foo[entry]
        start_position = entry
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> foo = ['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> [(i,[v[0] for v in list(v)]) for i,v in groupby(enumerate(foo, 1), lambda x: x[1])]
[('bar', [1, 2, 3]), ('foo', [4, 5]), ('bar', [6])]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think function below can help you

```
def fooRange(foo):
    a = []
    b = []
    #check if first value is equal to second value
    if foo[0] == foo[1]: 
        a.append(1)
    else:
        b.append([foo[0],1,1])
        a = []
    #loop for other values
    for i in range(1,len(foo)):
        if foo[i] == foo[i-1]: 
            a.append(i+1)
            if i == len(foo)-1: 
                b.append([foo[i],min(a),max(a)])
        else:
            if i == 1:
                a = [i+1]
            else:
                b.append([foo[i-1],min(a),max(a)])
                a = [i+1]
                if i == len(foo)-1: 
                    b.append([foo[i],min(a),max(a)])
    #prepare output
    for i in range(len(b)):
        if b[i][1] == b[i][2]:
            print('\''+str(b[i][1])+' = '+str(b[i][0])+'\'')
        else:
            print('\''+str(b[i][1])+'-'+str(b[i][2])+' = '+str(b[i][0])+'\'');

fooRange(foo)
```